# How to remove fill color and keep lines in Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I'm trying to work on a letter created with the Type tool that has been vectorised using "Create Outlines"... Now the letter is filled with a black color. I'd like to remove that color (and fill it with my custom color) and also give a different color to the curve around the fill.

How can I do that?

Comment: Select the object, and change the stroke and fill colours to whatever you want. This is really basic stuff. Perhaps best to have a look at some of the beginner tutorials on Adobe(dot)TV

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic: Tech support because this is a really basic Illustrator operation...

Answer (score 2):

Use the Color panel, the Swatches panel and the Color picker...

[image]

- [**How to choose colors in Illustrator - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/selecting-colors.html)
- [**How to use and create swatches in Illustrator - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/using-creating-swatches.html)